# Highcharts - column to spline drilldown with series data

Tags: highcharts, series, drilldown

Thanks to stackoverflow and other resources I've been able to manage having a column chart drilldown to a spline chart, as long as the spline chart only has one set of data.

I now would like the column chart to drilldown to a spline with series data so that the spline chart will show several lines, but I can't seem to get this to work.

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phdjsep/qjQPm/3/

If you can figure this out, could you please provide a brief explanation? I've been beating my head on the desk for days.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Of course I figure this out right after posting, but in case anyone else needs this, here's the answer: [http://jsfiddle.net/phdjsep/vNfWk/][1]


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/phdjsep/vNfWk/

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this example, I've had to add an additional js function for the drilldown to work properly:
http://jsfiddle.net/5De8h/6/

```
    function setChartMultiSeries(name, categories, series, color, level, type) {
        chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories);
        for(x = 0; x < chart.series.length; x++)
        {
            chart.series[x].remove();
        }
        for(x = 0; x < chart.series.length; x++)
        {
            chart.series[x].remove();
        }      

        for(x = 0; x < series.length; x++)
        {
            chart.addSeries({
                color: series[x].color,
                name: series[x].name,
                level: level,
                data: series[x].data,
                type: type
            });
        }

    }
```

Adam